# Hibernate will not persist data after save

Tags: spring, hibernate, save, flush, persist

Can someone explain why the "lastAccessed" date does not get saved to the database in this example and how I can get it to save to the DB?  My understanding is that the do object is an attached object after the save() call and therefore all modifications should be persisted automatically.

Note: "myDate" is persisted correctly, so all other spring configuration seems to be correct.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public DateObject getOrCreateDateObject(Date myDate) {
    DateObject do = null;

    do = getCurrentDateObject();  // For my tests, this has been returning null

    if (do == null) {
        // create a new object
        do = new DateObject();
        do.setDate(myDate);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(do);
    }

    // This does not persist to the database
    do.setLastAccessed(new Date());

    return do;
}
```

I have also tried some of the following combinations (and more) after the save() call.  None of these work:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(do);  // tried before and after do.setDate(d2)

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(do);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(do);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

DateObject doCopy = (DateObject)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(DateObject.class, do.getId());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(doCopy);
doCopy.setLastAccessed(new Date());
```

I'm hoping this is an easy answer that I'm just not seeing.  Thank you for your help!

Edit #1 05/22/2012

As requested, here is the mapping for this entity, specified in src/main/resources/META-INF/dateobject.hbm.xml.  I can see that the columns are created in the database using "SELECT * FROM dateObjects" in the mysql client.  MY_DATE is populated correctly, but LAST_ACCESSED is set to NULL.

```
<class name="com.example.entity.DateObject" table="dateObjects">
    <id name="id" column="DATE_OBJECT_ID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="date" type="date" column="MY_DATE" />
    <property name="lastAccessed" type="date" column="LAST_ACCESSED" />
</class>
```

Edit #2 05/24/2012

I have a working SSCCE at https://github.com/eschmidt/dateobject.  The interesting thing is that the web client (calling localhost:8080/view/test) shows that lastAccessed is set correctly, but when I check the database with the MySQL client, it shows that lastAccessed is NULL.  With this complete set of code, can anybody see why the database wouldn't update even though the method is marked @Transactional?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Is there a session open?

Comment: You need to call `save` after setting the `lastAccessed` date.

Comment: @RosdiKasim: False. The OP is correct in assuming that once attached to the session, the object's state will be persisted to the database.

Comment: Can you show us the mapping for `DateObject`?

Comment: @arturnt: I don't see any exceptions in the log.  I know there is a session open because do.date is successfully saved to the database.

Comment: @TimPote: hibernate mapping added to my post as Edit #1

Comment: @Eric, I come accross similar problem. What is your hibernate-core version? mine is 3.3.1.GA.

Comment: @GurselKoca: I am using hibernate 3.5.0-Final.

Comment: @Eric, well, I have solved my problem .. is lastAccessed field is not null?.. If it is not null, your problem is same with mine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain that after running that code, `do.date` is stored in the db and `do.lastAccessed` isn't, then your connection and transaction are obviously set up correctly. My first guess would be incorrect mappings, since that's the simplest solution. You don't happen to have an `@Transient` on the field, the getter, or the setter for `lastAccessed`, do you? (Assuming, of course, that you're using annotations to map your domain objects.)

If you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I'll bet I or someone else can give you a definitive answer.

**Update:** It's hard trimming a full application down to the smallest possible code that demonstrates a problem. The upshot is that you'll likely find the answer while you're at it. I have lots of [sample projects in github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed) that might help guide you if you just need a few nudges in the right direction. [basic-springmvc](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/basic-springmvc) might be closest to what you're doing, but it uses annotations instead of xml for mappings. It's also a Spring MVC project. It's a lot simpler to  start a Spring context manually in a main class than to worry about a whole servlet container and the multiple contexts that Spring MVC wants you to have. [spring-method-caching](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/spring-method-caching), for one, has an example of doing that.

As for the mapping you posted, it looks fine, though it's been a long while since I touched an XML mapping. Are you using field or property access? That could possibly have a bearing on things. Also, are there any custom [listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/EventListeners.html) or [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html) in the SessionFactory that might be twiddling with your objects?

Comment: He never merged/persisted/saved the object after modifying the in-memory copy. What does it have to do with the connection or tx?

Comment: As I've explained in my comment to your answer, you're just not getting how Hibernate works. It *doesn't matter* when you call save().

Comment: @RyanStewart: I added my hibernate mapping to the question.  I am certain that do.date is stored and do.lastAccessed is still NULL.  There is no Transient annotation on the field or the [gs]etter.  I will work on providing an SSCCE, but that may be difficult as this is an enterprise spring application.  Do you have any tricks on setting up an SSCCE for spring?  Thanks!

Comment: @RyanStewart: I've started to set up an SSCCE here: https://github.com/eschmidt/dateobject

However, I when I try to deploy this application to Glassfishv3, I get the following exception: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spring.framework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Do you know why it can't seem to find the spring-web jar?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the container. It's the wrong class name. `org.springframework`, not `org.spring.framework`.

Comment: @RyanStewart: Wow.  An extra pair of eyes really helps, thanks!  Now I can get back to focusing on the real issue...

Comment: @RyanStewart: Ok, I have a complete SSCCE ready at https://github.com/eschmidt/dateobject.  I also updated my original question with new findings.  See the edit above.

Comment: You've made the unfortunate mistake of committing your output directory along with all the dependent jars and packaged artifacts, making your repository ridiculously huge and therefore difficult to clone. There also doesn't seem to be a way to actually run the project if I were to clone the dozens (hundreds?) of MB of it. The ["Self Contained"](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) bit is supposed to mean that any Joe Schmoe can pick it up and run it to see what it's doing.

Comment: @RyanStewart: Sorry about that.  I removed all target directories.  Total size should be about 70k now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using IDENTITY generation for your identifier generation strategy, so the save() call here immediately translates to the insert.  Do you see any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE SQL executed after that?  If not, it is most likely that the session is just not being flushed.  flushing might happen at a number of points, read the docs on flushing if you are unfamiliar.

Comment: I tried calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); explicitly and it still will not save in the database.  If I search the log for LAST_ACCESSED, there are 46 lines returned.  However, looking at the last few lines of SQL, I see a "create table", a "select", an "insert" (but it only shows (?, ?), so I'm not sure what it's inserting - I assume this is the first save), and a "select".  I'm not sure why the "create table" seems to be coming so late in the game...

Comment: If you want to see what Hibernate binds to those PreparedStatement parameters, enable the logging category org.hibernate.type (Hibernate 3) or org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder (Hibernate 4) to TRACE

Comment: But here, I would expect an INSERT followed by an UPDATE.  Like I mentioned above, you are using IDENTITY so Hibernate has to perform the INSERT as soon as you call save()

Comment: Thanks for the logging tip.  I will enable that when I get back home to work on it.  Sounds like the SQL in the logs is in line with what seems to be happening in the app (saves the first date, but not the second).  Any other thoughts on why flushing the session won't write to the DB?

Comment: I would not say that it "saves the first date, but not the second".  It saves both dates on INSERT.  Just that at the time of INSERT "last accessed" value is null, so thats what gets written.  Yes, the issue you need to figure out is why the entity changes after that (to set the "last accessed") are not processed and does not translate to an UPDATE.  You might be better off switching identifier generators.  IDENTITY generation has other limiting problems in conjunction with ORM and I generally recommend against using it.

Comment: My underlying DB is currently MySQL. I was under the assumption that IDENTITY is required for MySQL auto generated primary keys.  Is that not true?  If not, what do you suggest instead?